# .net 5.0 Library usable in VBA

Tags: c#, .net

I have several "Libraries" I've written over the years all of which are used by a VBA enabled application. I call the Libs modules as they do a specific set of tasks such as WEB api calls and Custome general libs to augment VBA.

In years past all were in VB .NET, real easy to do, Enable COM visible and register for COM interop.  C# really not that bad had to build an Interface def and add GUIDs for Events, Interface and Class then same as VB.net.

But now the question how do I build an C# DLL (Library) COM visible under .NET 5.0?

I tried using .NET core 3.1 and failed miserably, DLL did not register. For .NET 3.1 it was suggested to write a wrapper which I couldn't get to work either. Tired to target .NET standard 2.1 got as far as calling the wrapper methods but failed calling into .NET core methods.

.NET 5.0 is here and anything I've found so far says it can be done but no samples yet. Any samples would be helpful.

The key here is most methods, properties, and events need to be used in the VBA app. The VBA app is NOT MS Office but a licensed "VBA" tool.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com

Comment: That is current for Core 3.0, but thought there might be an update to .net 5.0 as I've run into issues getting things working and the Docs are bit light.  The example seems to fail from being found by the VBA reference editor and yes I do know how to register COM ops.... been doing a lot of .net 4.x DLL with COM op both in C# and VB.  So been a bit frustrated wanting to move to .NET 5 and my main dev work.